# WebdriverWait Lambda Expression

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can someone explain clearly what is that Boolean generic type for ExpectedCondition ?

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd->((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Boolean is the return type of your lamda expression.
In your example, the final line of the javascript  `.equals("complete")` in javascript executor returns boolean value.

For e.g., below examples returns WebElement,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until((ExpectedCondition<WebElement>) wd->((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.getElementById(someid)"));

new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until((ExpectedCondition<WebElement>) wd-> wd.findElement(By.id("someid")););
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code of `ExpectedCondition` we can see:

```
public interface ExpectedCondition<T> extends Function<WebDriver, T>
```

That could be read as "Expected condition is a function that **always** accepts a `WebDriver` as a parameter and returns value of a **generic** type `T`>

In the code of `Function` we can see:

```
/**
 * @param `<T>` the type of the input to the function
 * @param `<R>` the type of the result of the function
*/
public interface Function<T, R>
```

Your function compares two objects:

1) `Object` returned by `executeScript("return document.readyState")`. Actually js `document.readyState` returns a `String` value loading/interactive/complete. [more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)

2) `String` "complete"

using method `.equals()` that returns a `boolean`value:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete")
```

So the return value of your function is a `boolean` and it should have been passed as a return value type but generics in java do no allow primitives so you have to use `Boolean`.

Generics in Java are compile-time construct - the compiler turns all generic uses into casts to the right type. Anything that is used as generics has to be convertible to `Object` and primitive types aren't.